# How to understand what preposition is associated with what meaning?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I have difficulty in understanding what preposition, after a verb, is associated with what meaning, and how interchangeable prepositions are.

For example, Merriam-Webster reports the following meaning for [difficulty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/difficulty):

> 1. the quality or state of being hard to do, deal with, or understand : the quality or state of being difficult

Example:

> has difficulty reading

So it looks like the form is "to have difficulty doing something".

Another meaning is:

> 3. : objection

Example:

> made no difficulty in granting the request

So for this case the form is "have difficulty *in* doing something".

Can I use this form for meaning 1?

Can I say "has difficulty *in* reading"?

EDIT: What I mean is this. "going to" something and "going away from" something have two different meanings. If the dictionary assign "difficulty in doing something" to meaning 3 (objection), how can I know that I can use this construction also for meaning 1 (hard to do)?

Comment: Just to be clear, "have difficulty" is one construction, but you're finding other uses outside that. There are many that treat it as a simple noun instead of a phrasal verb: "level of difficulty," "don't make difficulty for me"...

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can, and, what is more you can also use another preposition: "with".

- [backwardness in reading](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/backwardness_in_reading/1Us7AAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22difficulty+in+reading%22&pg=PA190&printsec=frontcover): Thus in examining a child who cannot read , or who has extreme difficulty in reading , it is advisable first to ascertain whether his speech is , or has been , in any way defective , or whether he has been unusually slow in speech ...
- [Reading Under Control: Teaching Reading in the Primary Schoolbooks.google.fr › books· Traduire cette page
  Judith Graham, ‎Alison Kelly](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Reading_Under_Control/xZxIcBQu2esC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22difficulty+with+reading%22&pg=PA159&printsec=frontcover) :  However, central to all definitions, the difficulty with reading is widely acknowledged. The British Psychological Society locates the reading-related difficulty at 'word' level: Dyslexia is evident when accurate and fluent word reading ...

To ascertain further these facts you might peruse the following pages: [difficulty in reading](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22difficulty%20in%20reading%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), [difficulty with](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22difficulty%20with%20reading%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) (corresponding ngrams: [1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=difficulty+in+reading&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifficulty%20in%20reading%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdifficulty%20in%20reading%3B%2Cc0), [2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=difficulty+with+reading&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifficulty%20with%20reading%3B%2Cc0))

The multiple possibilities a preposition affords is not a truly grammatical question; it is more a matter of semantics and pure usage. Common sense is often a guide, and sometimes usage is so realized that a given preposition  is used in various contexts. The upshot of this situation is that you have to verify the prepositions in a dictionary, which, avowedly, is not always helpful. Nowadays, there the additional help provided by ngrams and their associated pages of examples; those should not be neglected, although they must be used with care; hchecking the use that has been made of this new tool in the present answer, you will easily convince yourself of the well founded of this contention.

Comment: I mean, "going to" something and "going away from" something have two different meanings. If the dictionary assign "difficulty in doing something" to meaning 3, how can I know that I can use this construction also for meaning 1?

Comment: @robertspierre The distinction in the "going" examples is the distinction between "to" and "away from"; the meaning of "going" doesn't change. Seems to me this question is mainly about the phrasal verb "have difficulty ____" ["with," "in," or no preposition]. Do you want to edit to focus exclusively on that construction?

Comment: @robertspierre Either your reading experience tells you it is possible to assign another meaning, or a dictionary  tells you. But small dictionaries are not likely to list all the important prepositions. You will only get that from a dictionary such as the full size Oxford dictionary. In the present case my _Shorter Oxford English Dictionary_, which often lists alternative prepositions, was of no help.